# An oracle for real currency values

Tags: oracles

I would like to get an oracle for values of countries' based currencies.
Are there such free oracles?

Comment: You can make one using chainlink external adapters. All you need is a source, from which you want to bring the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chainlink's decentralized oracle network can easily facilitate this. You can either find your own data source or sources and make an [Any-API request](https://docs.chain.link/docs/request-and-receive-data) in your contract or depending on what data you want they already have a growing list of [currency exchange rates](https://data.chain.link/) in their list of data feeds. These are feeds that pull data from multiple high-quality sources, then have multiple oracles aggregate the data and post the final result on-chain, where it can be consumed by other smart contracts. More info in their [Price Feeds docs](https://docs.chain.link/docs/using-chainlink-reference-contracts)

Comment: Do you know is chainlink supports GraphQL APIs? I couldn't find anything in the docs, so I'm assuming no :(

Comment: Chainlink supports any API. The default adapters handle any HTTP GET, POST or PUT request, but if you need to do some custom code to handle other scenarios, you can use what are called external adapter, which is basically an API in itself that the chainlink node uses. Check out the docs  https://docs.chain.link/docs/external-adapters/ . If you show me an example of a GraphQL API call I can tell you what you'd need to use it using Chainlink

Comment: Super interesting. I'm actually just calling the Snapshot GraphQL API. The votes query from this endpoint actually. https://hub.snapshot.org/graphql?